Why doesn't this replace text in drafjs editor
I'm trying to learn draftjs. I've made an example where if you click a button it's supposed to insert some text in the editor, but I can't understand why it isn't working, clicking the button has no visible effect.
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Editor, EditorState, Modifier, SelectionState } from 'draft-js';
import 'draft-js/dist/Draft.css';
export class TextEditor extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
          this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createEmpty() };
          this.focus = () => this.refs.editor.focus();
          this.toggleText=this.toggleText.bind(this);
    }
    toggleText(){
        let currentEditorState=this.state.editorState;
        let selectionState = currentEditorState
            .getSelection()
            .set('anchorOffset', 0)
            .set('focusOffset', 5);
        let newContentState = Modifier.replaceText(
            currentEditorState.getCurrentContent(),
            selectionState,
            'Your new text here'
        );
        let newEditorState = EditorState.push(currentEditorState,
            newContentState, 
            'replace-text');
        this.setState({ editorState: newEditorState }); 
    }
    render() {
        return (<div>
                <div onClick={this.focus} className="TextEditor">
                    <button onClick={()=>this.toggleText()}>Toggle</button>
                    <Editor
                        editorState={this.state.editorState}
                        onChange={x=>this.setState({editorState:x})}
                        ref="editor"
                    />
                </div>
           </div>);
     }
}

